# How to get variable datasets in Charts JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have datasets that are in variable number. Means they can be 2,4 or 6 etc. So i need to plot those datasets on the chart. for manual plotting of each dataset it is working fine:

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

but if i do this:

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: ()=>{ [ return {label: '# of Votes',data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],borderWidth:1}
        ]}
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

It doesn't work. I have previously seen functions being used like i have written for `ticks`. but it is not working on `datasets`.
What i need to do is to iterate through a list and make several datasets into a dataset array from that (that code is not written here. if a function can be made then i can easily write the code for it to iterate). Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create self invoking function and which will return array of datasets like this.

```
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: (() => {
      return [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }];
    })()
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

or you can create a function outside which will return datasets array and call it like below

```
datasets: getDataset()
```